# Simple Expect Value Exercise

Tags: probability

**Question**: We have $9$ coins, $1$ of them is false (lighter). We divide them up in pairs (with one left) and weigh them (that is taking two in a balance and seeing if one of them is lighter). What is the expected value of *number of* weighings to find the false one?

I suspect this is a rather elementary problem, yet, whenever I solve these (or rather - when I think i solved them), I am never sure at all with my result being correct.

**My solution** The probability of the false coin being in any pair is $2/9$, therefore the probability $\mathbb{P}(X=t)$ that the false coin will be found is $2/9$ for $t=1,2,3$ and $3/9$ for $t=4$ since if it didn't show up in the last weighing, it must be the one left. Therefore:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{2}{9}(1+2+3)+4\frac{3}{9}=\frac{24}{9}$$

Is that correct and if not, why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your solution doesn't make any sense at all. You only need to state the weight of the coins (both normal and light). For example, if the weight of the coin is 100, then the expected value of the weighing is close to 200.

Comment: Or, are you asking for the expected number of weighing needed to find if the lighter coin is in a certain pair?

Comment: Are you trying to find a strategy for minimizing the number of weighings needed to find the false coin? You can do it in two.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't say *number of weighings*, added in now.

Comment: @Did  Are you sure?  A weighing means put one coin on each side of a balance scale.  The lighter one will show up, or if the scales balance the coin is not in that pair.

Comment: Yes, that is how it is meant, I am sorry about such a poorly defined question. I'll add in more details.

Comment: @Tim You are right. Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct for the technique you're using to find the coin.

The nine coins problem is a classic puzzle, it's usually phrased as a challenge to find the light coin with as few weighings as possible.

Your solution to that problem is not optimal.
Instead for your first weighing put three coins on each side of the scale. 
So you have sets groups of three coins, and you may deduce which set the coin is in.  Then you can find the coin with a second weighing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the additional helpful insight.